# Laravel 5 Validation in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 2 methods in my Controller and I need to validate it but I don't know how.

1st method which should allow all image extensions:

```
public function testing(Request $request) {
    if($request->hasFile('img')) {
        $image = Input::file('img');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path);
        $file = $request->file('img');
        return ['url' => url('images/' . $filename)];
    }
}
```

2nd method which should only allow 1 word and if there is space, trim it into 1 word:

```
public function postDB(Request $request) {
    $newName = $request->input('newName');
    $websites = new Website();
    $websites->name = $newName;
    $websites->save();
    return redirect('template')->with('status', 'Website has been saved successfully!');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First write new Request for your data

```
php artisan make:request ImageRequest
```

Than write in **ImageRequest**:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
       'img' => 'file|image',
    ]    
}
```

If you want to customize error messages:

```
public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'img.image' => 'Some custom message ...',

        ];
    }
```

Last inject request to your method (don`t forget about **use App\Http\Requests**):

```
public function testing(Requests\ImageRequest $request) {
    //for retrieving validation errors use:
      $imgErrors = $errors->first('img'); 
}
```

[More information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation) about **Form Request Validation**

Or you can use **Validator** facade (don`t forget about **use Validator**):

```
$validator = Validator::make(
            $image, [
                'img' => 'file|image',
            ]
        );
```

[More information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields) about **A Note On Optional Fields**

Comment: how about second function?

Comment: similar to the first method, just change the input

Comment: I don't know how to trim words if there is more than one.

Comment: trim it after validation ... $newName = trim($request->input('newName'));

Comment: I am getting: Class App\ImageRequest does not exist

Comment: where you store your **ImageRequest**?

Comment: it has created it in app/Http/Requests/ImageRequest.php

Comment: Why does it give me error 403 saying "Forbidden"? even thought I have selected an image

Comment: edit answer ... set 'return true' in **authorize** method

Comment: That works fine, how about if I want to display an error message saying "file type not allowed"?

Comment: that code goes into ImageRequest right? How do I call that function in a controller?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#working-with-error-messages information about working with error messages

Comment: Thanks that's brilliant, you have been a great help. From what I see if I want to validate to only allow alphabetic characters I need to use 'alpha' is that correct?

Comment: Was glad to help ) ... yes, you can use 'alpha' , Laravel provide a lot of useful validation rules

Comment: Problem is that if I use alpha and in name I have a space, validation fails and it doesn't trim the name